# How can I add nothing to the list in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am writing a list comprehension in Python:

```
[2 * x if x > 2 else add_nothing_to_list for x in some_list]
```

I need the "add_nothing_to_list" part (the else part of the logic) to literally be nothing.

Does Python have a way to do this? In particular, is there a way to say `a.append(nothing)` which would leave `a` unchanged. This can be a useful feature to write generalized code.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just move the condition to the last

```
[2 * x for x in some_list if x > 2]
```

Quoting the [List Comprehension documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

> **A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a `for` clause, then zero or more `for` or `if` clauses.** The result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in the context of the `for` and `if` clauses which follow it.

In this case, the expression is `2 * x` and then a `for` statement, `for x in some_list`, followed by an `if` statement, `if x > 2`.

This comprehension can be understood, like this

```
result = []
for x in some_list:
    if x > 2:
        result.append(x)
```